# To check: Overlapping of two RRULEs with different parameters and timeslot

Tags: time, overlap

I have to create an algorithm in which I will be provided with two different RRULEs with different frequency, interval, count and start. Also, the respective timeslots will be provided for these RRULEs to create time-ranges just like recurring events in the calendar. I need to check if the given two RRULEs with there respective timeslots overlap each other even once in the whole future till RRULEs are built.

RRULEs can be checked here: https://github.com/rlanvin/php-rrule/wiki/RRule

For now, I have thought of a way for a simple case in which I would first determine the lowest part of the time for which the two RRULEs will recurr(repeat) or gcd(greatest common divisor) of freq of two RRULEs and for that part of time check if the two timeslots overlap, then only go on to build RRULEs and compare.

For Ex:

> Freq1 = 3 days 
>   Freq2 = 2 days 
>   Therefore gcd = 1 day 
>   So I will check if timeslots in 1 day overlap each other by comparing their hours-minutes-seconds part and then only go to lengths of building the complete RRULEs.

The only problem here is that lots of case are to be considered for the various types of frequency combination of RRULEs.

If there is a better way or some library does this then please let me know.